# Remove AddThis from OC 3.0.2

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart, opencart-3

I'm using OC 3.0.2 and want to remove or be able to modify the AddThis script. I tried changing *product.twig* - removing the whole AddThis script - and refreshing the cache in OC admin panel - still didn't work. In the stylesheet, I added the class of addthis and styled - didn't work. The problem I have is the inappropriate styling of the twitter button. So, how do I go about it? My website is http://www.davoodkhan.net.

Comment: try this its can help you, remove all script and div of addthis from product.twig  and turn off the cache then clear the cache. then you will check product page.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to style AddThis Social share icons but you can remove it from product page to do that please search for this in product.twig

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" data-url="{{ share }}"><a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a> <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a> <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a> <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-515eeaf54693130e"></script> 
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

And remove it.

If Nothing changes then Please

1. Clear cache from dashboard.
2. Delete cache files from vqmod (delete
   all files from **root-folder/vqmod/vqcache**)
3. Refresh Extension Modification

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

try this its can help you, remove all script and div of addthis from product.twig and turn off the cache then clear the cache.

then you will check product page.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but I have just upgraded to OC3 and had the same problem, no amount of cache clearing made a difference and I see that it's still there on the OP's site so I thought I would share the fix that has worked for me.

I had created a child theme and had my own version of product.twig. After much searching I found a copy of the original product.twig that still contained the addthis code in the storage folder (the one you are told to move after installation). It wasn't in the cache folder though, which is why clearing the cache didn't help. It was in storage/modification/catalog/view/theme/*yourtheme*/template/product/
I deleted the file and checked. Fixed!